# calculating a quotient group of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm calculating a quotient group $A/B$ where
$$A:=\left\{ ax+by+\sum c_i z_i \middle|\, a,b,c_i\in\mathbb{Z}, \sum c_i =0 \right\}$$
$$B:=\left\{ x\sum a_i +y\sum b_i +\sum (a_{i-1}-a_i + b_{i-1}-b_i) z_i \middle|\, a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{Z} \right\}$$
$x,y,z_i$ are formal variables, sums are all $i=0,\ldots,n-1$ where $n$ is fixed,
and addition on indices is modulo $n$ (i.e., $a_{(n-1)+1}=a_0$).

The answer I expect is $A/B\approx\mathbb{Z}_n$, but I'm not seeing how to get there. Ideas?

Comment: Do you mean all the sums are from 1 to *some fixed, non-changing n*?

Comment: Then I'll edit your question: this is important info.

Comment: I still can't see how $\,B\leq A\,$...the sum of the coefficients of the $\,z_i\,$'s in $\,B\,$ is not necessarily zero.

Comment: Sorry, @Mike: I can't see how. We get: $$a_1-a_2+a_2-a_3...\neq 0$$ unless $\,a_1=a_n\,$, and the same for the $\,b_i's\,$ . And still I can't see your editing pointing out the fixed, unchanging n

Comment: I still don't get it: so you begin your sums from zero and up to n, yet **still**: $$\sum_{i=1}^na_{i-1}-a_i=a_0-a_1+a_1-a_2+a_2-a_3+...+a_{n-2}-a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}-a_n=a_0-a_n$$ so...why is $\,a_0=a_n\,$?? Even if you used coefficient from $\,\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\,$ , where did you add this further conditions? And BTW, the above sum *must* begin from $\,1\,$...

Comment: @DonAntonio: When I say "addition on indices is modulo $n$", I mean $a_{(n-1)+1} = a_0$. Likewise, $a_{0-1} = a_n$, so the sum needn't start from $i=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $i$, let $u_i=z_{i+1}-z_i$.  Then $A$ is generated by $x$, $y$, and the classes $u_i$ for $i=0,\ldots,n-1$, and has the relation $\sum u_i = 0$. In this notation, $B=\{x\sum a_i + y\sum b_j + \sum (a_i+b_i) u_i \mid a_i,b_i\in \mathbb{Z}\,\forall i\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Pick an integer $k$ and let $a_k=1$, $a_{k+1}=-1$, $a_j=0$ for $j\neq k$ and $b_j=0$.  Then $u_{k+1}-u_k\in B$.  Hence $\overline{u_k}=\overline{u_{k+1}}$ as elements of $A/B$. Therefore the value is $\overline{u_k}$ is independent of $k$; we will denote this value by $\bar{u}$.

You can easily check that $\bar{x}=\bar{y}=-\bar{u}$.  Then $\bar{u}$ generates $A/B$.  We have only the relation $n\bar{u}=\sum \overline{u_j}=0$; the relations $\bar{x}\sum a_i + \bar{y}\sum b_j + \sum (a_i+b_i) \overline{u_i}=0$ become $-\bar{u} \sum a_i -\bar{u} \sum b_j + \sum (a_i+b_i) \bar{u}=0$, which is trivial.  The group generated by $\bar{u}$ with the relation $n\bar{u}=0$ is of course $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Right, because $\sum d_i u_i = \sum (d_{i-1} - d_i)z_i$. You meant $u_k - u_{k+1}\in B$? Same conclusion. $a_k=1$ gives $x+u_k\in B$, so $\bar{x}=-\bar{u}$, etc. Clever.